# ggplot2 - geom_point `size` color gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm following [ggplot document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/ggplot2.pdf) and trying to adjust geom_point to a color gradient using the size variable.  Here is the code which includes the mtcars data set:

```
#Load data
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))


# Add aesthetic mappings
p + geom_point(aes(size = qsec))
```

I'd like to add a color gradient, but cannot get it work.  I tried adding doesn't `scale_colour_gradient` and `scale_fill_gradient` but these do not change the color.  Here is a sample of how I'd like to change the color:

```
#Load Data
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))

# Add aesthetic mappings
p + geom_point(aes(colour = cyl)) + scale_colour_gradient(low = "blue")
```

How can I use color gradients when I use `size`?  Note, this a repeat question, but per the responders suggestion, I'm adding data to the question.  Thank you.

**Solution thanks to eipi10**

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(aes(color=qsec, size=qsec)) + scale_colour_gradient(low = "white", high="green")
```

Comment: `size` and `color` are independent aesthetics. You can map one column to `size` and another to `color`: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = qsec, colour=cyl)) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "blue", high="red")`.

Comment: thanks for your response @eipi10.  I want to apply the color gradient to `size = qsec` not `colour=cyl`.

Comment: Okay, then do `aes(color=qsec, size=qsec)`.

Comment: that worked, thank you!!!